# Missing parameter type for expanded function when not assigned to a variable

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

I noticed a strange behavior of the Scala compiler. The code:

```
Seq("?").toSet foreach (println(_))
```

produces the following error:

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => println(x$1))
        Seq("?").toSet foreach (println(_))
                                        ^
```

Same happens with this:

```
Seq("?").toSet foreach (x => println(x))
```

I found two ways to get around this. Ether to specify the type explicitly:

```
Seq("?").toSet[String] foreach (println(_))
```

Or to save to a variable:

```
val s = Seq("?").toSet
s foreach (println(_))
```

Is this a reasonable behavior or a compiler bug? It doesn't make a lot of sense to me. How could this be explained?

Comment: Interestingly, the absurd alternative `Seq("?").toSet forall {x => println(x); true}` compiles and runs, while `Seq("?").toSet foreach {x => println(x); true}` fails with the `missing parameter type` compiler error. `println` does not seem to be the problem, as you can change the function to `x => true` and still have `forall` running and `foreach` yielding the error.

Answer (score -2):

It expands to:

```
Seq("?").toSet foreach (println(x=>x))
```

Comment: While this is a valid alternative, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Code-only answers are auto-flagged as low quality and as such are discouraged on stackoverflow. In the future please embellish your answer with details and explain why it is a solution to the question.